# KVM bridged guest ssh permission denied

Tags: ssh, kvm-virtualization

I am able to ping my virtual machine and also have a satisfying response from ssh service using telnet, but I get 'permission denied' error whenever I attempt a ssh connection from a remote host. Connection is just fine when connecting in loopback on 127.0.0.1 with the same credentials.

Any hints?

Comment: What does the logs show?

Comment: They just show authentication failure when connecting from external host, and also say that /etc/securetty is missing

Comment: Check your firewalls.

Comment: ufw disabled. It's as if password gets encoded wrong when entered from the ssh authentication terminal, but that's impossible

Answer (score 1):

Check:

- /etc/hosts.deny / hosts.allow
- "Match Address" in your sshd config

(i.e. something like:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
PubkeyAuthentication no
Match Address 127.0.0.*
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
    PasswordAuthentication yes
```

)

Comment: /etc/hosts.deny / hosts.allow are entirely commented out;
No 'Match Address' settings show up in sshd config